# Rails Webpacker, ignoring certain entries "packs" from recompiling every time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

is there a config or method to ignore certain packs from recompiling in development? the problem is my packs are gigantic in size and every time i make a change everything gets recompiled "webpack-dev-server.

I don't want to delete the entry files in the pack folder just for development.

Any ideas? thanks